# Мне нужно перекинуть в другую активити ArrayList<ImageView>. Как можно это сделать?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно перекинуть в другую активити ArrayList. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Перекидывать непосредственно виджеты (как ImageView) между активити очень плохая затея, которая создаст вам множество проблем на ровном месте. Виджет это только визуализация, в каждой активити они должны быть свои. Передавать надо данные, которые виджеты должны отображать. Каждая активити затем помещает эти данные в свой виджет. Например, для ImageView нужно передать имя файла картинки. То, что вы хотите сделать, это как тащить сам монитор туда, где вас попросили показать, что на нем, вместо того, чтобы отправить скриншот, например или ссылку на видосик там.

Comment: Спасибо за совет